# Not returning to intial css setting of display block after use of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation menu in with the nav-bar is hidden when the screen reduces below 767px.  I then use JavaScript to set the nav-bar to CSS property of display blocked.  The problem is when the user clicks the hamburger menu to hide the nav-bar again and resizes the widow above 767px the nav-bar does not show even though its original CSS property is set to display block.

Hopefully, this makes sense.

Any advice?

```js
var hamIcon = document.getElementById("hamburger-icon");

// open and close the navigation menu
hamIcon.onclick = function() {
  var navBar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
  if (navBar.style.display === "block") {
    navBar.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    navBar.style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

```css
#nav-bar {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: block
}

#hamburger-icon {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}


/* START OF MEDIA QUERIES */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #hamburger-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  #nav-bar {
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="top-bar-container">
    <i id="hamburger-icon" class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't set the nav bar to `display: none` explicitly when hiding the navigation on the second click, but rather remove the inline style by setting it to an empty string. Your CSS will handle the rest.

*(It's best to click "Expand snippet" to get this snippet working)*

```js
var hamIcon = document.getElementById("hamburger-icon");

// open and close the navigation menu
hamIcon.onclick = function() {
  var navBar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
  if (navBar.style.display === "block") {
    navBar.style.display = "";
  } else {
    navBar.style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

```css
#nav-bar {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: block
}

#hamburger-icon {
  display: none;
  /*color: white;*/
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}


/* START OF MEDIA QUERIES */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #hamburger-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  #nav-bar {
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="top-bar-container">
    <i id="hamburger-icon" class="fas fa-bars fa-2x">☰</i>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
    navigation
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Amaaaaazing!  Been trying to figure this out for ages.  So if my understanding is correct when you set navBar.style.display = ""; the element falls back onto it's original CSS properties??

Comment: Correct. When you set a style via JS, it is added as an inline style to the element, which has the highest priority in the cascade (except any values with `!important`). Setting the value to an empty string removes that inline style again.